# Accessing website search box in Java

Tags: java, html, web-search

What I need to write is a code snippet that would go to a website e.g. www.google.com find the search box put in the phrase and retrieve HTML code of results page/pages. Is it possible to achieve this in Java?

Answer (score 1):

> e.g. www.google.com

For Google, use the [JSON/Atom Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html).  It is the only (legal) way to access Google search.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use something like [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/), although there are other similar options.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you should be able to pass a parameter to the url (have a look at the google url after issuing a search, there are plenty of parameters) or use a post request (if the site supports it, check for an API description).

If you read the URL directly from Java (e.g. using the `URL` class) you'll get the returned HTMl as is.

Answer (score 0):

The first tool I thought of was Selenium. It is primarily a web testing framework, but can be used to automate a browser for the kind of operation you're suggesting.

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#getting-started-with-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

[HttpUnit](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/) can also be used. It's a well documented, open source and easy to use unit test framework.